# Can I do multiple prints on the same line in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

Here are my codes:

```
d={}

d["Mark"]="A"

d["Suho"]="B+"

d["Christine"]="C"

d["Ben"]="B"

d["Bin"]="A-"

for key, value in d.items():

    print("Name: ")

    print(key)

    print ("Grade: ")

    print(value)

    print("")
```

So I am trying to iterate over key-value from the dictionary. I am trying to make the outcome looks like this:

Name: Mark

Grade: A

But I am struggling to put multiple prints on the same line.

Comment: `print("Name:", key)` `print("Grade:", value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
d={}

d["Mark"]="A"

d["Suho"]="B+"

d["Christine"]="C"

d["Ben"]="B"

d["Bin"]="A-"

for key, value in d.items():

    print("\nName: " + key)

    print ("Grade: " + value)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using python 3 you can use f-strings

```
print(f"Name: {key}\nGrade: {value}")

#Name: Mark
#Grade: A
#Name: Suho
#Grade: B+
#Name: Christine
#Grade: C
#Name: Ben
#Grade: B
#Name: Bin
#Grade: A-
```

when you call `f` in front of a string, anything contained with `{}` will be called as a variable and print what is stored within.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for key, value in d.items():
   print("Name: {} Grade: {}".format(key,value))
```